# Using (NS)Predicate to make sections in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to query health kit to populate a UITableView in a similar way you would Core Data. There isn't anything like the NSFetchedResultsController, so making sections isn't as easy. Is it possible to use an NSPredicate to return the data as a multidimensional array to allow sections?

If not, how would one go about turning an array of (potentially thousands) of sorted HKObjects into a sections?